# How to Set a Value of Kconfig Option

Tags: command-line, kernel

I want to change the value of a specific `CONFIG_...` parameter (in here: `CONFIG_ATH5K_DEBUG`) inside Kconfig option.

I use `make menuconfig` command, press `/` and type `CONFIG_...` to find its location. Then

I go there, change the value and Exit > Save configuration. But it doesn't make any effects. I see in the Terminal:

```
End of the configuration.
Execute 'make' to start the build or try 'make help'.
```

So what is the point here? Do I have to run the `make` command to make effects? But everytime I run `make` command, there are always errors. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

When 'make menuconfig' is executed, you just edit a configuration file.

At the end of the edition, you need to issue 'make', to make effect of the configuration. It is always necessary to run 'make' to make effect of your configurations.

The problem is that you are having erros that do not have anything related to the configuration you just did. You system have some problem that you need to solve before trying to compile a kernel. And let me say: these problems are very common.